# How to assign vector to a reference variable?

Tags: c++, vector, tree

I have a vector,

```
vector <int> num;
```

I have a pointer to a structure

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

Treenode* a;
```

I want to assign `a->left` to a part of `num` vector  and `a->right` to another part (Basically I'm trying to find **max** in `num` and then construct left and right subtrees )

Comment: I think you say about `map` objects because you can add values with keys which you want.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.   There is no relationship between the `TreeNode` type and `int` or `vector<int>` types.   `left` and `right` must point at an instance of `TreeNode` (or be the null pointer), but cannot point at an `int` or a `vector<int>` or a "part of a `vector<int>`" (whatever that means) without circumventing the type system and (potentially) introducing undefined behaviour.

Comment: This question would have [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) without last sentence. Problem is that I do not fully understand last sentence. What problem your algorithm should solve?

Comment: You're approaching this from the wrong angle. The pointers should point to newly created `TreeNode`s, not into the vector.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take a pointer of a part of a vector, because it might reallocate, and every time you add something to the vector, all your pointers might become invalid.

Comment: You get iterators invalidated only if new size > current capacity